# Spring Kafka Producer logging

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to develop/debug a Spring KAfka application. I am using KafkaTemplate to serialize a POJO to JSON. However I m unable to log the actual serialized JSON text. Is there any way to log these details? What is the log configuration needed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are doing the serialization. If you are using a `StringJsonMessageConverter` in the template, with a `StringSerializer`, and use `send(Message<?>)`, a `ProducerInterceptor` configured in the Kafka properties will see the JSON.

If you are using the `JsonSerializer` it won't work because the interceptor sees the record before serialization. You would have to create your own `Serializer` that wraps the `JsonSerializer` and logs the output.